# database is not connected after tomcat restart it require reload project

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, struts2, subdomain

I have a Struts2 web application it runs on sub domain like http://www.abc.example.com.

When tomcat is restart, all domain and sub-domains are started and connected to database easily but my one Struts2 application that runs on http://www.abc.example.com is not connected to database till application is not reloaded again from tomcat manager.
I am using **phpMyadmin** as database and using JDBC connectivity for connect that.

my database Connection Class is-

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.sql.Connection;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;  import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource;

public class ConnectionResource  {
public static Map<String, DataSource> sessionMap=new HashMap<String, DataSource>();

 private static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
 private static String port = "3306";
 private static Connection connection = null;     
 private static String ip = "localhost";   
 private static String user = "root";     
 private static String password = "123456";   

 private static MysqlDataSource  dataSource=null;    

 /**          
 * @return the ip
 */
 public static String getIp() {
    return ip;  
 }

 /**
 * @param ip the ip to set
 */
 public static void setIp(String ip) {
    ConnectionResource.ip = ip;
 }

 /**
 * @return the user
 */
 public static String getUser() {
    return user;
 }

 /**
 * @param user the user to set
 */
 public static void setUser(String user) {
    ConnectionResource.user = user;
 }

 /**
 * @return the password
 */
 public static String getPassword() {
     return password;
 }

/**
 * @param password the password to set
*/
public static void setPassword(String password) {
    ConnectionResource.password = password;
}

private static DataSource createDataSource(String db) throws Exception{
    String url="jdbc:mysql://"+ip+":"+port+"/"+db+"";
    dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
    dataSource.setURL(url);
    dataSource.setUser(user);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);        
    return dataSource;
}

public static Connection getConnection(String db){ 
    try{
        if(sessionMap.get(db)!=null){
            return  sessionMap.get(db).getConnection();    
         }else{
             DataSource ds=createDataSource(db);
             sessionMap.put(db, ds);
             return ds.getConnection();
         }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}   
}
```

What is a problem?

Comment: please provide more details

Comment: please, we cant help you if you not explain better your problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you mention i feel just its not properly deploy.
Please mention more details for get the correct problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your valuable comments..
I fond the problem..
**there is a Logger problem.. Logger class is not initialize..**
***so my Quartz create a problem to connect database...***